# Program freezes and won't close when left click is simulated

Tags: python, c#, pyautogui, user32

It's as simple as that. I've been trying to code something that simply left clicks in a certain position, but no matter what programming language I use, the program fails to do so, freezes, refuses to close, and when trying to terminate it shows "access denied" and the only way to close it through restarting my computer. Please help me.

```
On Python: pyautogui.moveTo(x,y)
pyautogui.click(x,y)
```

Comment: How do you expect us to help without seeing any of your code?  Are we supposed to guess what you've done?

Comment: That's my bad. I'll update it

Answer (score 0):

Alright uh so i fixed it but I'm not sure how. I just downloaded an auto clicker because I was wondering if it would work. https://sourceforge.net/projects/orphamielautoclicker/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).